# Eclipse says that I don't have <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

Tags: java, android, manifest

Recently I updated my google_play_service_lib, but I have the next error in eclipse very nonsense, because I have such line in my manifest...

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 6587000 but found 7895000.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

This only happen when the version of my google_play services_lib is bigger than google_play_services_r26. I need to update to this version, but when I import it to my project I have that error. This is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="..."
android:versionCode="9"
android:versionName="2.3" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="99" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />  
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic2"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar" >

    <meta-data 
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />    
    .......
</application>  
</manifest>
```

Anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: post your Values folder... and also check the google play service lib virsion no 6587000??

Comment: my google play service lib version is 8487000, I tried to put it hardcoding, but it doesn't work too...

Comment: That's not the solution. I think that is because of I updated my google_play_service_lib, and maybe could be some conflict between .jar. But I don't know